# how to pass attr to forms.CharField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I want to pass some Html attr to a form field generated by crispy

I try to this code in django 2.2.3

```
class AddForm(forms.Form):
    todo = forms.CharField(max_length=128, attrs={'placeholder':'What do you want to do?'})
```

but I got an error

```
    from .forms import AddForm
  File "C:\Users\HP\django_project\todo\forms.py", line 4, in <module>
    class AddForm(forms.Form):
  File "C:\Users\HP\django_project\todo\forms.py", line 5, in AddForm
    todo = forms.CharField(max_length=128, attrs={'placeholder':'What do you want to do?'})
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 214, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'
```

Comment: use  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'What do you want to do?'})

Answer (score 2):

`attrs` is an argument to the widget, not the field.

```
todo = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'What do you want to do?'}))
```